# how to get click duration on pointerdown PhaserJs 3

Tags: javascript, input, phaser-framework

I want to get duration in real time while the user is clicking on a sprite with the event on **pointerdown**.

As I can see from PhaserJs v2 examples you can do this in that way
`game.input.activePointer.duration`

Instead of that I need to get the duration when the user is clicking on the sprite. My code with the event is

```
sprite.on('pointerdown', e => {
        console.log(game.input.activePointer.duration);
});
```

This code in PhaserJs 3 returns undefined.
I want to calculate the time that the user clicks down on **pointerdown** event and not in **pointerup**.

Comment: I think that I found a possible solution. I can get the time from the scene and calculate it with the downTime from the activePointer. So my code in the function update will do that 
function update(time, delta){
    console.log(time - window.game.input.activePointer.downTime);
}

Comment: No, it's not duplicate